# How to set up Oculus Mixed Reality Capture with Unreal

Tags: unreal-engine4, oculus

I'm trying to set up Oculus Mixed Reality Capture to capture footage of someone playing my VR game. I have got it to work with other MRC enabled games like Beat Saber but I don't understand how to enable MRC in my game. I followed [The Oculus Guide](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unreal/unreal-mrc/#configuration) and also had a look at [The Unreal Documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/WorkingWithMedia/MR/MRQuickStart/index.html) but it seems to be outdated.

From what I understand all I need to do is

1. Have the Oculus VR plugin enabled
2. Get the Oculus MR settings (in a blueprint)
3. Set IsCasting to true

[Oculus MR Blueprint nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uignd.png)

But I just get these errors.

```
Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None trying to read property CallFunc_GetOculusMRSettings_ReturnValue". Blueprint:  BP_BilpakkGameMode Function:  Execute Ubergraph BP Bilpakk Game Mode Graph:  EventGraph Node:  Load from Ini
Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None trying to read property CallFunc_GetOculusMRSettings_ReturnValue". Blueprint:  BP_BilpakkGameMode Function:  Execute Ubergraph BP Bilpakk Game Mode Graph:  EventGraph Node:  Set Is Casting
Blueprint Runtime Error: "Accessed None trying to read property CallFunc_GetOculusMRSettings_ReturnValue". Blueprint:  BP_BilpakkGameMode Function:  Execute Ubergraph BP Bilpakk Game Mode Graph:  EventGraph Node:  Save to Ini
```

Also I put in a IsMrcEnabled node in and it returns false.

[IsMrcEnabled node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtVXP.png)

Lastly I tried downloading the [Mixed Reality Sample](https://github.com/Oculus-VR/UnrealEngine/tree/4.26/Samples/Oculus/MixedRealitySample) from Github, but I couldn't get this to work either, I got the same errors.

I'm using Unreal Engine 4.26.2 and Oculus VR plugin 1.51.0 and Oculus Quest 2